Deciding whether two sets of permutations are isomorphic
I am looking for a way to decide whether two sets of permutations are isomorphic to each other.
For example, $$permlist=((1,2,3,4,5),(1,2,3,5,4),(2,3,1,5,4)).$$
$$permlist2=((4,5,3,1,2),(4,5,3,2,1),(4,3,5,2,1))$$
I want to check if these permutation sets are isomorphic. My plan was to turn them into adjacency matrices
graph1s=Table[AdjacencyMatrix[PermutationMatrix[permlist[[i]]]],{i,1,3}]
graph2s=Table[AdjacencyMatrix[PermutationMatrix[permlist2[[i]]],{i,1,3}]

Then I was going to use IsomorphicGraphQ for each element of the first list with every element of the second list, to make sure that each element of the first list is isomorphic to at least one different element of the second list. However, I imagine there must be a better way to figure out if two SETS of permutations are isomorphic without going to all of this trouble?

PermutationCycles converts a permutation to a unique canonical form. Perhaps that will help you?

Definining G1 = PermutationGroup[{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 5, 4}, {2, 3, 1, 5, 4}}] and G2 = PermutationGroup[{{4, 5, 3, 1, 2}, {4, 5, 3, 2, 1}, {4, 3, 5, 2, 1}}] we can see that GroupOrder[G1] is 6 and GroupOrder[G2] is 120. Therefore these lists of generators cannot generate isomorphic groups. Evaluating G1 == G2 will tell you if two groups of permutations are identical, but not whether they are isomorphic under some homomorphism.

Using FindGroupIsomorphism from the Wolfram Function Repository, we see
ResourceFunction["FindGroupIsomorphism"][
PermutationGroup[PermutationCycles/@permlist],
PermutationGroup[PermutationCycles/@permlist2]
]

returns{} which means that the permutation groups generated by these sets are not isomorphic.
